# Make width to have auto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to make the width of the select to have auto width but it doesn't work.

What part am I missing?

I'm using bootstrap v3 with bootstrap-select

```
Demo: http://jsbin.com/fedusazilo/edit?html,output
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should override bootstrap css, add below line of code in your css. 
hope it will help you.

```
.bootstrap-select:not([class*=col-]):not([class*=form-control]):not(.input-group-btn) {
width: auto !important;}
```